# How do I show decimals in Javascript that adds values from text boxes?

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript (combined with ColdFusion for looping) that automatically adds values from a textbox. How can it display decimal format?

```
<script language="javascript">
function getValues(val){
<cfloop from=1 to=3 index="j">
var numVal#j#=parseInt(document.getElementById("#j#").value);
</cfloop>

var totalValue = 
<cfloop from=1 to=3 index="k">
numVal#k# + 
</cfloop>
0;

document.getElementById("main").value = totalValue;
}
</script>
```

Result:

```
<input type="text" id="main" value="24" readonly>
```

Comment: Your loop uses parseInt, which will remove any decimal places from the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to convert to decimal format(say two decimal places) you can use the function as below.

if totalValue is a string representing numerical value:-

```
document.getElementById("main").value = parseFloat(totalValue, 10).toFixed(2);
```

if totalValue is already a number then you can simply do `totalValue.toFixed(2);` Not too sure about ColdFusion syntax but seems like you are already getting a number so you may go with the second approach.

**http://jsfiddle.net/J5Lur/**

Comment: It displays the decimal OK. But if I enter like 1.5 and 2.0 on the text box, it does not add as 3.50. It only shows 3.00 as the result.

Comment: Here is my code for the textbox: <input type="text" size="3" name="MyNumber" id="#f#" value="8.00" onkeyup="getValues(#f#)" /><br

Comment: is your text box names #1# #2# etc.. not sure about CF syntax. :(

Comment: My textbox are named as MyNumber1, MyNumber2, etc.... but I have a hunch the problem is with the script. Tried the two lines that you suggested but I only get x.00 result. Thanks.

Comment: Can you use javascript instead of coldfusion for that operation? Did you check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/J5Lur/?

Comment: Should this line be ParseFloat instead of ParseInt? var numVal#j#=parseInt(document.getElementById("#j#").value);

Comment: Yes that is the problem, You should use parseFloat. Also give the base as 10 too, see my example...

Comment: I have updated my answer with the link to the fiddle, so that you can check.